# Getting weird split screen on startup with msi radeon hd6450?

Tags: installation, ati, configuration

I had this problem with same card last month on my dads dual boot setup to where the card worked in windows but not in ubuntu.Tonight I got a new system running with this card I installed ubuntu as only os and the install went fine,but upon reboot and first entering ubuntu my screen is split in half where my unity bar is in the middle.Can anyone tell me how to step by step install what I need to do to get everything in working order with this card?I really cant access much because ubuntu wont let me and i am pretty much a newbie still.I did read from one of my questions about my dads about compatible ati cards and it is listed but how can I install the drivers I need if my screen is split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how your screen is split, but I think there is a keyboard way to get there.

Hit the Super Key (aka Windows Key).  That should open the dash.
Type Additional Drivers and hit Enter.  That should open the Additional Drivers window.

Now this is where I don't know how to go on just with the keyboard.  This is what the Additional Drivers window looks like on my system, but yours will have some differences.

[image: Additional Drivers]

You can see where the buttons are so you might, through a bit of experimentation, find where to click to do what you need.  The "Remove" button on the lower-right was, before the drivers were activated, an "Activate" button; it's possible that it's the only button you'll need to press, but be careful you don't delete the drivers from something else (such as a wireless adapter).  I don't know, but you might also have to choose to download the drivers, although they're probably already there.

Comment: I finally got in with unity 2d and picked a driver.Up and running now thanx so much for the answers here

Comment: one thing-I have my system up and running with this card because I could get to my proprietary drivers even in split screen.However my dad has this same graphics card and gets no split screen just a blank screen.I did learn though I can get to a place to put in commands.Can anyone tell me the command I can use on his computer to get his fglrx driver installed?